# Airflow: Dynamically generate tasks with TaskFlow API

Tags: airflow

Previously I used the following snippet to dynamically generate tasks:

```
dummy_start_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id="dummy_start",
    default_args=default_args,
    python_callable=dummy_start,
    dag=dag
)

make_images_tasks = list()
for n in range(WORKERS):
    globals()[f"make_images_{n}_task"] = PythonOperator(
        task_id=f'make_images_{n}',
        default_args=default_args,
        python_callable=make_images,
        op_kwargs={"n": n},
        dag=dag
    )
    make_images_tasks.append(globals()[f"make_images_{n}_task"])

dummy_collector_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id="dummy_collector",
    default_args=default_args,
    python_callable=dummy_collector,
    dag=dag
)

dummy_start_task >> make_images_tasks >> dummy_collector_task

# in collector_task I would use:
# items = task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids=[f"make_images_{n}" for n in range(int(WORKERS))])
# to get the XCOMs from the these dynamically generated tasks
```

How can I achieve that using the TaskFlow API? (Spawn multiple tasks and then get their XComs in the following collector-task)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an example:

```py
from datetime import datetime

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.decorators import task

with DAG(dag_id="example_taskflow", start_date=datetime(2022, 1, 1), schedule_interval=None) as dag:

    @task
    def dummy_start_task():
        pass

    tasks = []
    for n in range(3):

        @task(task_id=f"make_images_{n}")
        def images_task(i):
            return i

        tasks.append(images_task(n))

    @task
    def dummy_collector_task(tasks):
        print(tasks)

    dummy_start_task_ = dummy_start_task()
    dummy_start_task_ >> tasks
    dummy_collector_task(tasks)
```

Which gives the following DAG:
[image]

The `make_images_*` tasks take 0, 1, and 2 as input (and also use it in the tasks' id) and return the value. The `dummy_collector_task` takes all outputs from the `make_images_*` tasks and prints `[0, 1, 2]`.

Comment: This answer is super helpful, thanks so much. The documentation on airflow's own website regarding TaskFlow is so sparse, it's barely sufficient. That being said, what if I had to create the `make_images_i` using some loop logic inside `dummy_start_task`. How can that be achieved?